# n-gram modeling with java hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap, n-gram

I need to model a collection of n-grams (sequences of n words) and their contexts (words that appear near the n-gram along with their frequency). My idea of was this:

```
public class Ngram {

    private String[] words;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> contextCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
```

Then, for the count of all the different n-grams, I use another Hashmap, like

```
HashMap<String, Ngram> ngrams = new HashMap<String, Ngram>();
```

and I add to it while receiving text. The problem is, when the number of n-grams surpasses 10,000 or so, the JVM Heap fills up (it's set to a max of 1.5GB), and everything slows down really badly.

Is there a better way to do this, so to avoid such memory consumption? Also, the contexts should be easily comparable between the n-grams, which I'm not sure is possible with my solution.

Comment: What size are we looking at for these? About how many words per n-gram? Also, do you have auxilary memory being used, like large temporary memory? Don't forget that a hashmap can be a memory intensive structure while it resizes!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with those n-grams? Did you have a look at lucene using a n-gram-tokenfilter? Maybe you can use a lucene index to perform the tasks you need to perform. You can then either keep it in your memory or store it to the file system.

Comment: I have around 50,000 news articles I'm collecting the ngrams from. After processing 6000 articles, the average size of a context Hashmap in Ngram is around 13. I don't have any auxiliary memory, at least I don't think so :)

Comment: I am trying to find semantically similar n-grams by comparing their context vectors. I have looked a little into lucene but it seems that their n-gram definition is character based, not word based like mine.

Comment: If the map contextCount is usually small and the number of different contexts is also small and fixed, consider changing the contexts to an Enum and using an EnumMap. Both String and HashMap have lots of overhead for small data, that may be where your memory is going.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use HADOOP MapReducer for Huge database (normally for Bigdata). use Mapper to split the input to Ngrams and combiner and mapper to do whatever you want to do with those Ngrams.

```
HADOOP uses <Key,value> as like you wish to process with Hashmap.
```

I guess its something like Classification. so it well suits. But it requires cluster.

if possible, you can better start with **Hadoop The Definitive Guide (Orielly publications)**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already found the solution to your problem, but there is a very nice approach to large scale language models on this paper:

Smoothed Bloom filter language models: Tera-Scale LMs on the Cheap

http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/D/D07/D07-1049.pdf

Comment: Link to the paper is dead, here's a mirror: http://www.learningace.com/doc/1789441/13c59f831d31425f78311337bd7cb4fa/d07-1049